# In Magento How to Show the Bundle Products Option in Front end Tab (Product View Page)

Tags: tabs, bundle, magento-1.9, catalog

In the front end product view page, I need to show the bundle product options in the custom Tab.

I have added the new custom tab in front end product view page.

I have pasted the below code in this file.

> template/catalog/product/view/custom-tab.phtml

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    echo $_product->getName();
```

Here product name is showing, But bundle product option is not showing.

Please assist me. How to achieve this.

Thanks